# clang-tidy incorrectly replaces template parameter in typedef

Tags: c++, clang-tidy

I ran clang-tidy over a selection of my codebase, and noticed a few typedefs including template parameters being incorrectly replaced with concrete types. I managed to replicate at least one of this issues with this example file, test.cc:

```
template <typename T>
struct Test
{
    typedef T test_1;
    typedef T test_2;
    typedef T test_3;
    typedef T test_4;
    typedef T test_5;
    typedef T test_6;
    typedef T test_7;
    typedef T test_8;
    typedef T test_9;
    typedef T test_10;
    typedef T test_11;
};

int main()
{
    Test<int> test;

    return 0;
}
```

running `clang-tidy-6.0 -checks=modernize* test.cc` on this file results in warnings to replace all of the `typedef`s with `using`s, but oddly, the third and fourth typedefs replace `T` with `int`:

```
/home/john/test/test.cc:6:2: warning: use 'using' instead of 'typedef' [modernize-use-using]
        typedef T test_3;
        ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
        using test_3 = int
/home/john/test/test.cc:7:2: warning: use 'using' instead of 'typedef' [modernize-use-using]
        typedef T test_4;
        ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
        using test_4 = int
```

All the rest of them have `T`, as expected. For some reason, this behaviour only seems to happen once there are 11 or more typedefs.

Is this a known bug? Is there a workaround so I can have clang-tidy automatically apply fixes without incorrectly replacing a bunch of typedefs?

Comment: Looks like a bug I would say. What is your question?

Comment: Is this a known bug? Is there a workaround so I can have clang-tidy automatically apply fixes without incorrectly replacing a bunch of typedefs? Will edit post to add actual question.

Comment: What if you insert a few empty lines between some of the typedefs? You may have better luck figuring out if this is a known bug by posting on the clang mailing list.

Comment: Nope, adding empty lines doesn't seem to have any impact.

Good idea about checking with clang directly. Did some searching on llvm bugs board and came across this (https://bugs.llvm.org/show_bug.cgi?id=32517), which mentions template parameter substitution along with a few other issues, but without specific code to reproduce the problem. Have applied for an account to be able to add this example.